# Spotify API: Is there a way to determine when a song has finished playing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, spotify

I'm trying to build an application that would utilize Spotify's API to build a playlist, I'm wondering if there is a way to determine when a song has finished playing?

I have checked their API and can't seem to find anything that I could ping or setup a callback for when it's complete.

I have looked at this question: [How can I tell if a song has ended or the next button was clicked with the spotify API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14009006/how-can-i-tell-if-a-song-has-ended-or-the-next-button-was-clicked-with-the-spoti)

although I'm unsure of what API was being used.

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks