# Spotify SDK in Swift 3.0: how to know when a song ends

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, spotify

I'm building a personal app in Swift using the Spotify api, and one thing that it needs to do is to play another song once the song that was playing is over. I have the ids to the songs all ordered the way I want them to be, and I can play them successfully.

I just need to know if there's a way to tell when a song is at its end so I know when to start playing the next one or to do other things (I make a HTTP request every time a song ends for another reason).

Any suggestions or any resources you could point me to is incredibly helpful! Couldn't find an answer through google searches :(

[Spotify API: Is there a way to determine when a song has finished playing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40209083/spotify-api-is-there-a-way-to-determine-when-a-song-has-finished-playing)

This is a similar question that was posted but it was for javascript and it was never answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement the `SPTAudioStreamingPlaybackDelegate` protocol, set the Spotify player's `playbackDelegate` property and implement `didStopPlayingTrack`. An example class would look something like this:

```
class MyClass: NSObject, SPTAudioStreamingPlaybackDelegate {
    var player = SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance()


    func setup() {         // Whatever function does the setup.
        player?.playbackDelegate = self
    }

    func audioStreaming(_ audioStreaming: SPTAudioStreamingController!, didStopPlayingTrack trackUri: String!) {
        playNextSong()      // Or whatever else you wish to do here.
    }

    func playNextSong() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

(Note that the setup function could be anything--such as `viewDidLoad` if the object observing the player is a view controller rather than subclassing `NSObject`.)

Because `didStopPlayingTrack` is a [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) function, the Spotify SDK should manage when it gets called (more specifically, the player should call it on its delegate object)--you don't need to call it yourself as long as the player's delegate is set.

Comment: I'm a bit new to Swift, so I'm a little confused by the audioStreaming function being declared. Would we pass in player as the first parameter (since it is the SPTAudioStreamingController)? Can you elaborate how to use this function a little more? I very much appreciate it :)

Comment: I updated my answer a bit--let me know if that still doesn't clear things up!

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! Made more sense when I read up a little more on swift protocols. You're a lifesaver!